# Cube bounces back with rigidbody and script in Unity

Tags: unity, movement

I have Unity 4.6.1 and I added a cube with a moving script and a rigidbody. The script is:

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float = 10.0;

function Update () {

    // Is the user pressing left or right (or "A" & "D") on the keyboard
    var horMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    // Is the user Pressing up or down (or "W" & "S") on te keyboard
    var forwardMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (horMovement) {
        transform.Translate(transform.right * horMovement * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    if (forwardMovement) {
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * forwardMovement * Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

And the rigidbody freezes position Y and freezes rotation X, Y, and Z. How do I stop it from bouncing back?

Comment: By bouncing you mean the slight movement backwards?

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov Yes I do mean that.

Comment: I've already wrote my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use physics instead to move your object like rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3). Using physics will solve your problem with bouncing.

Comment: Where do I add that?

Comment: Instead of transform.Translate()

Comment: I replaced the whole line but it didn't work.

Comment: Your line should look like this GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(YOUR VECTOR3 * SPEED);